# How WordPress Plugin Handles Form Submission

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I'm building a WordPress plugin for the first time and I would like to ask how does a WordPress plugin handles a typical form submission.

So for example if I am creating a search plugin with the url at http://wordpress/plugin-name/search, how do I display to the user the result page at http://wordpress/plugin-name/result ?
Do I have to create the result page and send user to the page programatically within the plugin itself?

Any resources or example that I could get would be much appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

It depends on the thing that the plugin have to do but normally yes, you have to create the result page and send the user there.

What are you trying to build, i may suggest something more specific if i know more details?

Comment: I'm planning to build an appointment booking plugin for clinics, so after the user searched for the clinic that he want to book an appointment with, how do I display the result to the user? So I'm guessing that I have to pre made a search result page, and use GET or POST?

Comment: You should use nested custom post types then, check this out [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types)